# why do i need to click two times to play audio

Tags: java, android, audio

I create a MediaPlayer to play audio with same button. When I click to play the audio first time it is work, after that when i press again to play the same audio I must click another press to play the Audio (2 times). How can i fix this.

**The play Audio method that I use**

```
    private void playAudio() {
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.play_audio);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            final AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            final int originalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.testa);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp1 -> mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, originalVolume, 0));
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, your current logic is that each click **either** starts or stops playback - not both. So I'm not sure why you expected any other result.

Comment: my guess, the first time you click, mediaPlayer == null returns true, the second time, it isn't,, so, extract the code in your if block to a method, which you also call after the execution of the code currently in the else block

Comment: Try reading the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is clear that you have two branches in the click listener, only one branch allows playing the mediaPlayer; so you must be falling in the other branch on the first click.

A possible fix of that to force release the mediaPlaer resources when the playing is completed so that you always make sure that you go to the first branch on the next click:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp1 -> {
    mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, originalVolume, 0);
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;             
});
```